# Illustrator CS5 converts all the missing fonts of an imported PDF into vectors, how do I substitute the fonts so I can edit the text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, pdf, cs5

All the missing fonts of an imported PDF are converted into vectors in Illustrator CS5, how do I substitute the fonts so I can edit the text?

Comment: Welcome Ronen! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

If type is converted to outlines it is done to maintain appearance. Your *only* option is to reset the type and delete the outlines if needed.

**There is no way to un-outline type in Illustrator**, other than using `Undo` if you outlined the type yourself.